In django path error when try to submit the normal user regitration from
typ<form action="register" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name"><br>
    <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="confirm_password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    </form>e here

def register(request):
    # print("in register")
    # if request.method=="GET":
    #     return render (request,"register.html")
        
    if request.method=="POST":
        print("IN POST")
        first_name=request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        username=request.POST['username']
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']
        confirm_password=request.POST['confirm_password']
    
        user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
        user.save()
        print("User Created")
        return redirect(home)
        # if password==confirm_password:
        #      if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        #         print("Username Already Taken")
        #      elif (User.objects.filter(email=email)):
        #              print("Email Already Taken")
        #      else:
        #            user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email,first_name=First_name,last_name=Lirst_name)
        #            user.save()
        #            print("User Created")
        #            return redirect('/')
        # else:
        #     print("Password and Confirm Password Does Not Match")



    else:
       return render (request,"register.html")

Expecting redirect to home page but its showing error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/register
Using the URLconf defined in Finance_Tracker.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
[name='home']
register/ [name='register']
admin/
The current path, register/register, didn’t match any of these.

action="register" This is the reason.  Because the action does not start with a slash, it is appended to the current url.  Put a slash in front.  action="/register"

Your form is on a page with the url /register/
but your HTML form tag has action="register"
...that form action is a 'relative' url, so when you submit the form it tries to  post the data to <current url> + register i.e. to /register/register
Put a slash in front action="/register" ...this turns the action into an 'absolute' url, so it will replace the existing path segment when submitting the form
Or better use the Django url tag to use derive the url from the named view in your urlconf
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url
e.g. action="{% url 'register' %}" ...here 'register' is the name of the view, not the url itself
see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/#examples
